# install mbstring extension on heroku

Tags: php, heroku

I am trying to install mbstring extension on heroku and the only info i found
on the web is this github site.

https://github.com/wuputah/heroku-libraries/tree/master/php

Generally the process is:

1. Download code in a heroku run bash that's a PHP app
2. /app/php/bin/phpize
3. ./configure --with-php-config=/app/php/bin/php-config
   make

When i run no 2 on and i got this, but i already at the root level of my site. Any idea?
Make sure that you run '/app/php/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a custom buildpack with support built-in to PHP for that. Here's a shameless plug to the buildpack that I use that has support for most of the common requests for PHP extensions.

https://github.com/winglian/heroku-buildpack-php